# In Excel VBA code use Thunderbird to send email, not Outlook

Tags: excel, thunderbird, vba7

How do I set Eapp object to Thunderbird and not Outlook?

I am able to automate emailing a PDF of a newly created Excel file (invoice) from within Excel using VBA.The the email client is Outlook but client prefers to mail with Thunderbird. I have not been able to make this change.

Current Code:

```
Sub EmailAspdf()

Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim EItem As Object
Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
```

How can I set Thunderbird as the EApp?